# CanExecute problem when switching to MVVMLight

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I had been using `RelayCommand` that I copied from an article ([probably this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern)), and the `CreateExamCommand` below worked fine, with `CanExecute` bound to whether `Name was empty.

#### XAML

```xml
<UniformGrid Columns="2" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
    <Button Content="Cancel" Command="{Binding CancelCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <Button Content="Create" Command="{Binding CreateExamCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
</UniformGrid>

<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBox Name="textBox" Tag="Exam Name" 
             Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

#### Csharp

```cs
public RelayCommand CreateExamCommand => new RelayCommand(
  () => CreateExam(Name, Date),
  () => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_name)
);
```

However, I just installed MVVMLightLibs, to replace my manually copied code (and deleted my versions of `RelayCommand`). Now the `CanExecute` method of `CreateExamCommand` is broken.

I put some `WriteLine`s inside the `CanExecute` and it appears to only run when the view(model) is loaded for the first time.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which version of MVVMLight's RelayCommand you're using.

If you have the namespace "GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf" then your command will use the CommandManager object and automatically refresh CanExecute after each keystroke or mouse click.

If you have "GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command" then you have to trigger CanExecute manually - add `CreateExamCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` in the setter of your Name property.

Comment: Actually, I'm just going to start using PropertyChanged.Fody. But this answer definitely seems right and relevant.

Comment: One of the few downsides of using Fody.PropertyChanged is that is no setter to use as a trigger - not that this is necessarily the right place to refresh commands anyway. I've discussed an alternative method in my blog - http://peregrinesview.uk/mvvm-commands/